# How do I make these sentences more natural?

Tags: grammar

I'm stuck with finding a more natural way of saying the following sentences. They are translations of Japanese sentences. I'm helping a Japanese guy with these.

( 彼女があなた達の中でもっとも年上ですか？)
Is she the oldest in you? 
Yes, she is the oldest in us.
No, she isn`t the oldest in us.

( 彼女が姉妹の中でもっとも年上ですか？)
Is she the eldest in your sisters?
Yes, she is the eldest in my sisters.
No, she isn`t the eldest in my sisters.

I think it's wrong to use "in" so I suggested to switch to "among/out of". 
I'm leaning towards using "among" but I'm not sure if it's the most natural way of saying this. I feel like the entire sentence is a little bit unnatural.

As in "Is she the eldest among your sisters?", "Yes, she is the eldest among/out of my sisters".

What do you guys think?

Comment: All you have to say is *of*:  Is she the oldest of you?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following combinations:

> - Is she the Is she the oldest [one] among you? Yes, she is the oldest [one] among us. No, she isn't the oldest [one] among us.
> - Is she the eldest of your sisters? Yes, she is the eldest of my sisters. No, she isn't the eldest of my sisters.

Comment: The 中 (inside, middle) probably refers to "your family," not "among you." The Japanese find it more polite to use directions or place locators when referring to people.